# Is javascript still client-side scripting language after Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It says "javascript is client-side scripting language" in all sources.

Node.js and web browsers are a runtime evnvironment. Both has JS engine. For example; V8 engine is included in Chrome and Node.js.

Does using Javascript in Node.js change the definition of "javascript is client-side scripting language"?

Which of the following definitions may be correct?

1) "We can develop server-side applications using Javascript with Node.js, but since Node.js is "runtime environment", this does not change that Javascript is client-side. Javascript is definitely a client-side language."

2) "Javascript is both server-side and client-side language."

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure if this is really on topic or a trick question, but there is no question that JS is more than a client-side language. For that matter, it's more than a server-side and client-side language.

Comment: JavaScript !== Node.js

Comment: javascript is a language that can run on client-side thanks to javascript engines in the browsers and can also run on server-side thanks to nodeJS

Comment: JavaScript is a *programming language*. It runs in many contexts, the most *ubiquitous* is client-facing web-browsers. Those "sources" are applying an artificial limitation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the other comments answered your question, but in the interests of writing good questions, I would just suggest that you include a link to some of the sources you mentioned. That way people could understand what you're referring to.

Comment: all languages can run on the side you choose to run it, as long as you have a compiler for it. You could compile php to js and run it in the browser. Thanks to WRTC and dht the a client's browser could be your server :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has had applications for programing outside of "client-side scripting" since at least [1998](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6411-10/contents.htm).

So it isn't true to say it is *exclusively* a client-side scripting language, and hasn't been since no later than 3 years after it was created.

Node.js doesn't change that.

> 2) "Javascript is both server-side and client-side language."

It's general purpose. There are plenty of uses of JS that don't involve client-server situations at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When we write a server-side application, Node.js runs the that javascript code. In this case, isn't Node.js client? Because our javascript code is running on Node.js. Just like a web browser. Can you explain about this situation?

Comment: No. The web browser is the client because it makes HTTP requests to a server. Client-side JS is code that runs on the client.

Comment: For example; We are create an "index.js" file and write "console.log('hey')" in this file. And we are execute our file with "node index.js" command. This will return "hey" on screen. Where is browser? Is not our browser Node.js in this case? Is not Node.js client? Is not our code running in Node.js?

Comment: There is no browser. There is no client. There is no server. There is no network request. It's a local application.